# Angular filter on a subarray

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a search box in an Ionic application. I have a nested array and I would like to search objects, which contain keywords in their subarray. Unfortunately, I get an error, when I try to filter in this way:

```
return this.bookingList.filter(booking => {
  return booking.acf.name_of_guest.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
});
```

My array looks like this and I would like to focus on the "acf" subarray only.

```
0:
  ID: 662
    acf:
     comments: "Test"
     date_of_reservation: "2020-10-27"
     e-mail: "xxxxx@testmail.com"
     name_of_guest: "Peter Tester"
     number_of_guests: "5"
     status_of_reservation: "1"
     time_of_reservation: "08:40"
```

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: yes, the variable seems to be undefined -> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: booking.acf.name_of_guest.toLowerCase() is a `string`, simply do `return booking.acf.name_of_guest?.toLowerCase() === searchTerm.toLowerCase()`

Comment: 1. It isn't a "subarray". It's an object inside the array element. 2. Please share more info. Where is this filter attempted? Does it depend on any async data?

Comment: it seems that `name_of_guest` not always exist. console.log(booking.acf.name_of_guest) and console.log(booking.acf) to find out

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
return this.bookingList.filter(booking => {
  return booking.acf.name_of_guest?.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

many thanks to your support. After long try & error I found the issue. The fourth object in the array had an empty acf subarray. This caused an error.

How I found this issue:
I consoled log the booking variable and saw that on the fourth iteration it showed an undefined variable. After that, I checked the entry on the db and saw that there were no data available. I deleted this dummy entry and then the filter worked as excepted.

```
return this.bookingList.filter(booking => {
console.log(booking.acf.name_of_guest);
  return booking.acf.name_of_guest.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
```